# Autonomous Talend job fails with 'Error: Could not find or load main class...'

Tags: java, jvm, talend

I have exported a Talend (5.2.0) job as an autonomous job and deployed it to my production server (Windows 2008 R2 Standard 64bit). I have found the JVM and added it to the PATH environment variable of the server as it was not being found.

The JVM in question is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)

When I attempt to run the batch file I get the following error.
Error: Could not find or load main class

The automated process works correctly on my laptop (which also has Talend installed locally). The server does not have Talend installed. I didn't think that installing Talend on the server would be necessary if I exported the job as an autonomous one.

Is there a setting that I need to implement to get this job to work?

Edited to Add--
After further testing I've found that I had been testing with slightly different versions of the packaged job. The one that worked was generated from Talend 5.1.2 and the one that doesn't work  came from Talend 5.2.0. This could be the cause of the problem.

Another Edit--> Further investigation shows that 5.2.0 is generating jar files for the job classes that are only 1KB in size whereas with 5.1.2 the jar files are significantly bigger (around 128KB). I think this is probably a bug with Talend 5.2.0. I've raised it with Talend who are investigating.

Comment: It looks like this could be a bug. I've reported it to Talend.. Bug reference to follow..

Comment: For those interested here is the bug reference https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-23693

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the job was failing to compile was that the workspace folder path had a space in it. This caused the compilation of the job to fail.

To mitigate this always use a Talend workspace folder that resides in a path that contains no space characters.

e.g. C:\Talend\TalendWorkspace will work and C:\Talend\Talend Workspace will not work.